# I have a mysql table contains lot's of records

Tags: mysql, select

I have a mysql table contains lot's of records. my table has a varchar field and a timestamp field. (I have one record for every minute)

I want to select records like this:

1,3,5,7,9,11,...

or 1,4,7,10,13,..
or something like this.
I can get done it using php while function, but it is not a good solution. is there any mysql select parameter to get it exactly from mysql?

p.s: sorry for post title, this is the only title stackoverflow accept it.

Comment: What are these numbers? Are they random or are you following some progression?

Comment: It is just sample. I have timestamp and an auto-increament field

Comment: Showing Odd/Even number results is easy. But do you want to configure... what all rows you want to show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select * from table  where identity_column %2 <>0 -- to select 1,3,5,7,9...
```

and for your 2 condition do this !

```
select * from table where identity_column%3 =1 -- to select 1,4,7,10,13,....
```

Answer (score 1):

For selecting records like 1,3,5,7,9,11,etc. You can do this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName
WHERE autoIncreamentField % 2
```

**NB:** Not necessary to check where clause against 0 or 1. It will select records if where clause returns 1. An example in [**Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69d61/16).

For records like 1,4,7,10,13,etc. You can do:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TableName
WHERE (autoIncreamentField % 3)=1
```

Comment: you need to specify condition in first query! `<>0`... i dont know in mysql but in sql server it'd give u `error`

Comment: @861051069712110711711710997114: No!! No need of that. It will select the records if where clause returns 1. An example in [**fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69d61/16).

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table order by rand()
```

Comment: Please review my post again, these are not random numbers.